# How to apply multiple coupon codes on cart / quote in Magento 2.3.x?

Tags: magento2, coupon, coupon-codes, magento2.3.x

Need custom logic to apply multiple coupon codes on a Cart / Quote  in Magento 2.3.x.
Core Magento allows to apply only one coupon code on Cart. However, I need to apply multiple coupon codes on an order.

Comment: You will need a third-party extension

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But, I would like to build it and need direction on how to implement the custom extension.